# MyBatis multiple resultsets

Tags: mybatis, multiple-resultsets

I am currently migrating code from iBatis 2 to MyBatis 3.  I have a function that returns multiple results sets which we map to different classes.  In iBatis we where able to map the different results using a comma separated list int the resultType like so:

```
<select id="findCashItems" parameterType="map" resultType="AdminCashBalance, AdminCashMovement, AdminCashTrx">
    exec RequestActualAdministrativeData #{portfolioId}
</select>
```

But this does not appear to work in MyBatis 3.  I can't find anything in the documentation except for a configuration item that, by default, enables multiple resultsets.  But nothing on how to actually process them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a resultMap with a comma separated list of result maps fixes this issue.

```
<resultMap id="adminCashBalance" type="AdminCashBalance">
...
</resultMap>

<resultMap id="adminCashMovement" type="AdminCashMovement">
...
</resultMap>

<resultMap id="adminCashTrx" type="AdminCashTrx">
...
</resultMap>

<select id="findCashItems" parameterType="map" resultMap="adminCashBalance, adminCashMovement, adminCashTrx">
    exec RequestActualAdministrativeData #{portfolioId}
</select>
```