# Does mybatis support stored procedures that return more than 1 result sets?

Tags: ibatis, multiple-resultsets

I'm porting a project from C# + SQL Server to Java + MySQL. I used ibatis 3 in the Java + MySQL project.

In the old projects, it used lots of stored procedures, which return more than 1 result sets.

I tried to find a solution using ibatis, and find this [MyBatis multiple resultsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388605/mybatis-multiple-resultsets).

It seems James Woods has make it using comma-separated resultMap list.

I tried his method and call the method in Java like:

1: Object[] findCashItems(); 2: List[] findCashItems();

However, both of them failed.

I just wonder does the ibatis 3 really support stored procedures that return more than 1 result set?

If so, how could we call the method in Java?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't know this tool you're using, but from a SQL-perspective, I would suggest you package the results you want returned by the stored-proc into a temporary table and return select * from temp-table. this will give you everything you need without worrying about the capabilities of your tool.

Comment: thanks slashmais for your answer. However in the old project which am porting now, the store procedures may return multiple result sets, each of them has different columns. So it's hard to pack them into a temp-table.

Answer (score 0):

Last I checked, you need a return type like `List` or `List<List<?>>`.